# Convert Type Decimal to Hex (string) in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a Decimal to Hex as a string. I've looked all over for a solution to this, but all I can find is Int or long to Hex. When using the code below I receive a "Format specifier was invalid" error.

```
    Decimal decValue = 18446744073709551615
    string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

I've also looked into converting the decimal to a byte array and then converting to Hex, but I'm coming up short on that also.

Comment: How do you want to treat non integral `Decimal`s?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How do you want to represent 234.567?

Comment: If `decValue` is integral, you can simply cast it to `BigInteger` and call `ToString("X")` on that. But if that's the case, you might want to use `long` or `BigInteger` instead of `decimal` in the first place. `((BigInteger)decValue).ToString("X")` works for your example.

Comment: if you are referring to a decimal that is not a whole number, my answer is - I don't need to handle them, because I am only dealing with whole numbers. I just need to use the type Decimal, because I am dealing with very large numbers in .net 3.5

Comment: When you're on an older version of the Fx you should mention/tag that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Just for the record, decimals can be converted into other bases, here are some binary examples that are easy to follow 1.5 = 1*2^0 + 1*2^{-1} and 0.25= 2^{-2} etc..

Comment: Note also how finite expansions in some bases might be infinite in others  such as 1.2 = 1.0011001100110011...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using .NET 3.5, how about [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/) which will work for .NET 2.0+?

```
var intx = new Oyster.Math.IntX(decValue.ToString());
intx.ToString(16);
```

For .NET 4.0+ use `System.Numerics` (remember to include `System.Numerics.dll`)

```
Decimal decValue = 18446744073709551615;
var bigValue = new BigInteger(decValue);
bigValue.ToString("X");
```

Of course this ignores any portion that is non-integer.

Comment: Since I am working with .net 3.5 I am unable to use BigInteger. Sorry I should have made that clear in my post.

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning `System.Numerics.dll` - most answers leave that important bit out.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using .NET 3.5, you'll have to do it by hand.  You can wrap it up nice and neat in an extension method:

```
public static class DecimalHelper {
public static string ToHexString( this Decimal dec ) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while( dec > 1 ) {
        var r = dec % 16;
        dec /= 16;
        sb.Insert( 0, ((int)r).ToString( "X" ) );
    }
    return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
Decimal dec = 18446744073709551615;
var hex = dec.ToHexString();
```

Comment: I didn't test your code, but another answer (that should have been a comment) claims that you need to replace `while( dec > 1 )` with `while( dec > 0 )`