# simple int to hex conversion not working

Tags: c#, int, hex

I have a very simple code where I get a value from numeric updown which I have then to convert to hex. (for numericupdown `Hexadecimal` property is set true)

I select `FF` from nud located in winForm. then in code

```
string str = nudID.Value.ToString("X");
```

But this is not working and I am getting format exception

Comment: What is the contents of `Value`?

Comment: it shows that it is 255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumericUpDown value isn't Int type, it's Decimal. Maybe here is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`NumericUpDown.Value` returns `Decimal`. [`Decimal.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support "X":

> The format parameter can be any valid standard numeric format specifier except for D, R, and X

Adapting some code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389888/2392683), try this if you are on .NET 4.0 or later:

```
string str = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(nudID.Value).ToString("X");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string str = nudID.Value.ToString("X2");
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
string str = ((int)nudID.Value).ToString("X");
```

You need to parse the decimal value to int. You can make it a bit safer by using TryParse if you want to.